# Java. Implement interface methods (that have some arguments) as methods with no arguments

Tags: java, interface

This is my interface:

```
public interface RandomName {
    public  String getName(List<String>list);
}
```

As you can see one argument is passed.
This is my first implementation:

```
public class RandomStudentName implements RandomName{
    
    @Override
    public  String getName(List<String>list) {
        String delimiter =" ";
        List<String> firstName = FileParser.getANestedListFromAList(list, delimiter).get(0);
        List<String> lastName = FileParser.getANestedListFromAList(list, delimiter).get(1);
        Shuffler.shuffle(firstName);
        Shuffler.shuffle(lastName);

        return firstName.get(0)+" "+lastName.get(0);
    }
}
```

I call it like this:

```
public class StudentBaseBuilder implements BaseBuilder {
    
    public NameBase build(Integer baseSize) {
        NameBase nameBase = new NameBase();
        RandomName randomName = new RandomStudentName();
        FileReader fr = new FileReader();
        while(nameBase.getBaseSize()<baseSize) {
            nameBase.addName(randomName.getName(fr.readFileFromResource("names.txt")));
        }
        return nameBase;
    }
}
```

Here is my second implementation:

```
public class RandomGroupName implements RandomName{

    @Override
    public String getName(List<String> list) {
        Random r = new Random();
        Character c0 = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
        Character c1 = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
        Integer i0 = r.nextInt(10);
        Integer i1 = r.nextInt(10);
        
        return c0.toString()+c1.toString()+"-"+i0+i1;
    }
}
```

And its calling:

```
public class GroupBaseBuilder implements BaseBuilder{

    @Override
    public NameBase build(Integer baseSize) {
        NameBase nameBase = new NameBase();
        RandomName randomName = new RandomGroupName();
        while(nameBase.getBaseSize()<baseSize) {
            nameBase.addName(randomName.getName(null));
        }
        return nameBase;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have to pass `null` so that everything works

My goal is 1) to get a random combination of people's names in the case of `RandomStudentName`. Here I read a file with these names and shuffle them. 2) to get a random combination of two characters and two digits in `RandomGroupName`. In this case, I don't have a file but a simple script.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to implement an interface method with one parameter and with no parameters at all?
2. Is it worth making an interface in this case at all?

Comment: What benefit do you get from having one interface for these two use cases?

Comment: Why are you trying to implement the method without parameters? Is this a requirement from you teacher?

Comment: @NomadMaker it is not. I thought as far as these classes do the same thing: give me random names, it is worth making an interface for them.

Comment: These examples seem very different to me. I wouldn't bother with trying to force them into an Interface.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was worried about: it's not worth making a single interface in this case.